# Why function inside an struct works C language

Tags: c, struct, function-pointers, gcc6

As shown in this small script.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct student{
    short count;
    void (*addCount)();
};

void student_addCount(struct student a){
    a.count++;
}

int main(){
    struct student student;
    student.addCount = student_addCount;
    student.count = 0;
    student.addCount();
    student.addCount();
    student.addCount();
    student.addCount();
    student.addCount();
    printf("%d\n",student.count);
}
```

I have added a pointer to a function inside a struct, but I do not know why this works as the function 'addCount' is not receiving any arguments and it actually adds up the number of times specified.

I am compiling this code with GCC 6.3.0 in different environments such as ideone.com, wandbox.org and the compiler in WSL.

here is the proof that it works with ideone.
https://ideone.com/Cam4xY

Comment: Undefined behavior is allowed to seem to work.

Comment: Enable all compiler warnings, and use a standard-compliant compiler.

Comment: Well, it's broken code with undefined behavior. To answer what it actually does, you need to look at the generated assembler code.

Comment: What compiler options did you use? With `-O2` I'm getting `0`.

Comment: I have enabled all compiler warnings and I do not get any warnings at all, gcc is not a standard-compliant compiler? I do not know what -O2 flag does, I am currently running it with "gcc prog.c -Wall -Wextra"

Comment: `-O2` enables "normal" compiler optimizations. gcc is technically not standards compliant by default; you need `gcc -pedantic -std=...` for that (where `...` represents the C version to use, e.g. `-std=c99`). But that's besides the point.

Comment: _"I have added a function inside a struct"_ No you haven't

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance, that is why I got here in the first place, but there is no need to be rude. And thanks to everyone for teaching me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not a function inside a structure, it's a function pointer inside a structure.

```
void (*addCount)();
```

defines `addCount` as a pointer to a function. The function returns `void` and takes an unspecified number of arguments.

That's what the empty parentheses mean. That's an old-style non-prototype function declaration. There is rarely, if ever, a good reason to use non-prototype function declarations or definitions. If you want to specify tht a function takes no arguments, use `(void)` rather than `()`.

```
student.addCount = student_addCount;
```

The function `student_addCount` takes a `struct student` argument, but its type is still compatible with the type of your pointer member. Assigning it like this essentially disables checking on calls. This is why old-style function declarations are a bad idea.

```
student.addCount();
```

This is an indirect call via the function pointer.  Since the function pointer type doesn't specify how many arguments are expected, the call is legal. Since the actual function being called requires a single argument of type `struct student`, the behavior is undefined. With old-style function declarations, it's entirely up to you, the programmer, to get the arguments right; the compiler won't help you.

Since you're getting what appear to be valid results, it's likely that the argument you expected to be passed happened to be in the right place in memory, perhaps on top of the stack. The function is called and it assumes, quite reasonably, that you've passed a proper argument value. It looks for that argument in memory, or in a register, and finds ... *something*.

Here's a version of your program without the undefined behavior:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct student{
    short count;
    void (*addCount)(struct student a);
};

void student_addCount(struct student a){
    a.count++;
}

int main(void){
    struct student student;
    student.addCount = student_addCount;
    student.count = 0;
    student.addCount(student);
    student.addCount(student);
    student.addCount(student);
    student.addCount(student);
    student.addCount(student);
    printf("%d\n",student.count);
}
```

The output is `0` -- because the `count` being incremented is a member of the parameter, which is a local object.

Here's a version that does what you probably want. It passes a pointer to the structure, so the `count` member of your original `struct student` object is incremented by the function. The output is `5`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct student{
    short count;
    void (*addCount)(struct student *a);
};

void student_addCount(struct student *a){
    a->count++;
}

int main(void){
    struct student student;
    student.addCount = student_addCount;
    student.count = 0;
    student.addCount(&student);
    student.addCount(&student);
    student.addCount(&student);
    student.addCount(&student);
    student.addCount(&student);
    printf("%d\n",student.count);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was pretty educational.